# How can I have global :var binding for org-mode code block header?

Tags: emacs, org-mode, org-babel

With emacs/org-mode, I can define variable binding per code block, as demonstrated below.

```
#+HEADER: :var release="release-0.5"
#+begin_src shell :results output verbatim
echo $release
#+end_src

#+RESULTS:
: release-0.5

#+HEADER: :var release="release-0.5"
#+begin_src shell
echo "Indeed the release is $release"
#+end_src

#+RESULTS:
: Indeed the release is release-0.5
```

However, I wonder if there is a way to avoid the duplication, to define the variable binding globally, or per section?

I tried the following, it does not work:

```
* Release Package the script to be portable
:PROPERTIES:
:header-args:var: release="release-0.5"
:END
#+begin_src shell :results output verbatim
echo $release
#+end_src

#+RESULTS:
: 
#+begin_src shell
echo "Indeed the release is $release"
#+end_src

#+RESULTS:
: Indeed the release is
```

EDIT: (adopting @Enze Chi's suggestion)
The following still doesn't work:

```
:PROPERTIES:
:header-args:shell:var release="release-0.5"
:END
#+begin_src shell :results output verbatim
echo $release
#+end_src

#+RESULTS:
:

#+begin_src shell
echo "Indeed the release is $release"
#+end_src

#+RESULTS:
: Indeed the release is
```

I wonder if there is a way to make it work?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The name of the property is `header-args:shell`; the value of the property is `:var release="release-0.5"`. The syntax of a properties drawer is <sup>1</sup>:

```el
:PROPERTIES:
:NAME: VALUE
:END:
```

so in this case:

```el
:PROPERTIES:
:header-args:shell: :var release="release-0.5"
:END:
```

Note that the name of the property has to be wrapped in colons (`:`) and there has to be a space after the ending colon to separate the name part from the value part, because that's how property names are syntactically recognized.

So the colon before and after the name of the property (`header-args:shell`) is part of the property drawer syntax, the colon in `header-args:shell` is part of the name itself, and the colon in `:var release="release-0.5"` is part of the value itself; and you *need* a space between the "colonized" name and the value. You got to keep your colons straight!

See [Property Syntax](https://orgmode.org/manual/Property-Syntax.html#Property-Syntax) and [Using header arguments](https://orgmode.org/manual/Using-Header-Arguments.html#Using-Header-Arguments) in the Org mode manual for all the details.

---

[1] Note that the property drawer must follow the heading *without any empty lines*. If the heading has planning information (`SCHEDULED` or `DEADLINE`), the property drawer follows the planning information, again without any empty lines (either between the heading and the planning information or between the planning information and the property drawer). See [Property syntax](https://orgmode.org/manual/Property-Syntax.html) in the manual or [Property drawers](https://orgmode.org/worg/org-syntax.html#Property_Drawers) in the Org syntax document on Worg.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed instruction! Following yours, after executing C-c C-c to activate it, it works as expected.

Comment: For future me since I just spent some minutes on this: the PROPERTIES drawer has to be just below the headline (and it's 'planning' line --e.g. DEADLINE--) ([7.1 Property Syntax. in Org 9.6](https://git.savannah.gnu.org/cgit/emacs/org-mode.git/tree/doc/org-manual.org?h=release_9.6#n5166:5170)). 
I had an empty line above `:PROPERTIES:` and it didn't work. Foolproof: use the `org-set-property` command.

Comment: Yes, indeed: here are some references that are perhaps more convenient [Property Syntax](https://orgmode.org/manual/Property-Syntax.html) and [Property drawers](https://orgmode.org/worg/org-syntax.html#Property_Drawers) in the `Org Syntax` document on Worg. I'll add a note to the answer too.

Answer (score 1):

Should be the language after `headers-arg`
`:header-args:shell: :var release="release-0.5"`

Comment: @Enize Chi I tried your solution. It seems still doesn't work as shown my edit in the question.

Answer (score -1):

The following syntax worked for me:

```
:PROPERTIES:
:header-args+: :shell :var release="release-0.5"
:END:
```

Comment: You are adding (`+`) to the `header-args` property for *every* language *two* header args: the arg `:shell` and the arg `:var release="release-0.5"`. It just so happens that the `:shell` arg is meaningless and  it is ignored, but the second "works" (at least after I fixed the misspelling). But just because it "works", that does not mean that it is correct (e.g. it would affect code blocks in other languages). See my [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70483855/2561714) for the correct specification.